# return undefined from service.ts in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm learning angular and I have a problem with getting data from service. This is my code ..

code from component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { RegisterService } from '../services/register.service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-register',
   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
  })
  export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  contact:string;

  constructor(private data : RegisterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(f){
  console.log('value from component.ts',f.value)

  if(f.valid){
  // "username":username,
  // "email":email,
  // "password":password,
  // "c_password":c_password,
  // "contact":contact,
  // "type":"user"
  // }
  console.log('type',f.value.type)
this.data.register(f.value.name,f.value.email,f.value.password,f.value.c_password,f.value.conatct,f.value.type)
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)});
   }
  }

}
```

The problem is  getting data from service.

code from service.ts is

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Body } from '@angular/http/src/body';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })


 export class RegisterService {

 API_URL = "http://..";

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 register(name,email,password,c_password,contact,type){

  let body ={
    "name":name,
    "email":email,
    "password":password,
    "c_password":c_password,
    "contact":contact,
    "type": 'user'
    }
    console.log('body from service',body);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Accept" : 'application/json',
      "Content-Type" : 'application/json'
    })

return this.http.post(this.API_URL+"register",body,{headers :headers});
    }
   }
```

Here contact is return undefined in console. I'am a newbie in angular 6. The screenshot of console is adding here.
[The screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfAC2.png)

Comment: whats your error in console? It is saying error 401, which is regarding to API you are hitting for registration.

Comment: @AnsBilal error 401 is because the contact is undefined.

Comment: just contact is undefined ?

Comment: @AnsBilal yes only contact is undefined

Comment: I guess you miss-spelled "f.value.contact". Check your spellings and inform me again

Comment: @AnsBilal thanks contact is  get but showing 401 error.. Is this problem is because of datatype ??

Comment: I am not sure about the API you are using for registration. Whats its request requirements. Test API in postman before you test it in code

Comment: @AnsBilal its is correctly working on postman getting 200

Comment: then check you request headers and body are you making request correctly. Make sure you are not missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I miss-spelled "f.value.contact". Now it is ok

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sending every value to service, just send f.value and try again.
check your log of console you should get every data that is passed from component.ts to service.ts